# Как разбить строку на слова и разделительные знаки?

Tags: java

Требуется чтобы массив содержал слова и знаки предложения на одном уровне, вроде:

```
"Hello, World!"
["Hello", ",", "World", "!"]
```

Пропуски, табуляция в результирующем массиве не имеют значения.
Каждый знак считать как один символ: `"..." -> [".",".","."]`

Comment: Многоточие должно быть одним "словом" или тремя? Как насчет скобок? А "?!" это один или два "слова"?

Comment: @Kromster уточнил в вопросе

Comment: Как вариант, split на подобную регулярку: https://regex101.com/r/CLtwV3/1 String[] result = new String("Hello, World!").split("\\\\w+\\|[\\\\s\\\\S]");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хмю Тут много вариантов.

Самы короткий, это одним Regex'ом. Фишка в том, что при сплите, символы съдеаютя. Чтобы этого избежать, можно использовать look ahead.

`"Hello, World!".split("((?=,|\\.|!)|\\s)");`

Правда есть проблема, если строка начинает с символа, например ",Hello", то первый символ уже не будет распознан.

Второй вариант чуть подлинее, вам его уже в комментариях подсказали, только не через split, а просто через find. Нужно будет использвовать Pattern, Matcher, в общем почитайте как регулярке в Java работают )

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\w+|,|\\.|!").matcher("Hello, world!");
List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
while(matcher.find()) {
    results.add(matcher.group());
}
restults.toArray();
```

Не самый оптимальный вариант за-за использования промежуточного списка, но цель была не в этом )

Comment: Да, это то что мне нужно, не силён в сложных регулярках, надеюсь разберусь, как появится время :)